# How to get the titles of all opened inspectors in outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

C#, VSTO, Outlook 2016.

I want to get a list of the titles of all opened Inspectors in Outlook.

The first call of Outlook.Application.Inspectors[1].Caption returns "Message" as the inspectors caption.
But the window-title of the inspector shows the subject of the email.

But when I open more inspectors then the caption seems to change.

So there is always one inspector in the collection without the
emails subject and the Inspector.Caption doesn't match the coresponding
window-title.

So how could I get a list of the right window-titles?

Coresponding code:

```
  private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
    m_Application = this.Application as Outlook.Application;
    m_Inspectors  = m_Application.Inspectors;

    m_Inspectors.NewInspector += new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(m_Inspectors_NewInspector);

    void m_Inspectors_NewInspector(Outlook.Inspector Inspector) {
      if (Application.Inspectors.Count > 0) {
        Debug.WriteLine("\n=== [Test] ================================");
        Debug.WriteLine($" Inspectors.Count: {Application.Inspectors.Count}");
        Debug.WriteLine(" Application.Inspectors: ");
        foreach (Outlook.Inspector CurrentInspector in Application.Inspectors) {
          Debug.WriteLine($"   {CurrentInspector.Caption}");
          Debug.WriteLine($"   --> {CurrentInspector.CurrentItem.Subject}");
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("===========================================\n");
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Dmitry Streblechenko, this does the job:

For reference:

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("[Test]: startet");

      // Variables
      m_Application = this.Application as Outlook.Application;
      m_Inspectors = m_Application.Inspectors;

      // Events
      m_Inspectors.NewInspector += new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(m_Inspectors_NewInspector);
    }

    void m_Inspectors_NewInspector(Outlook.Inspector Inspector) {
      Outlook.Inspector m_Inspector = Inspector;
      ((Outlook.InspectorEvents_Event) m_Inspector).Activate += new Outlook.InspectorEvents_ActivateEventHandler(m_Inspector_Activate);
    }

    void m_Inspector_Activate()
    {
      if (Application.Inspectors.Count > 0) {
        Debug.WriteLine("\n=== [Test] ================================");
        Debug.WriteLine($" Inspectors.Count: { Application.Inspectors.Count}");
        Debug.WriteLine($" Application.Inspectors: ");
        foreach (Outlook.Inspector CurrentInspector in Application.Inspectors) {
          Debug.WriteLine($"  {CurrentInspector.Caption}");
          Debug.WriteLine($"  --> {CurrentInspector.CurrentItem.Subject}");
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("===========================================\n");
      }
    }
```

But be aware of that the Activate-Event is called more often. So every time you
change or close an Inspector-window the event is fired.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you can have more than one inspector, hence having a list of wrappers (each holding Inspector object in a member variable and providing the event handler) would be more appropriate. You can also disconnect the Activate event handler after it fires once.

Comment: Hm, I tried to learn the wrapper-thing, but unfortunately MS decided to delete all the code samples. Are there any sources for these samples on the web?

Comment: There is not much to it - create a class that has `Inspector` object as one of its members and` Inspector.Activate` event handler as one of its methods. When `NewInspecto`r event fires, create the wrapper and add it to a list of wrappers. When `Activate` fires, you will know which `Inspector` object it corresponds to. When `Close` event fires, you can remove the wrapper of the list.

Answer (score 0):

`NewInspector` event handler is probably too early - try to hook up the `Inspector.Activate` event: it fires when Inspector is visible.